# Ramdomly replace each entry by one of its four neighbours

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I iterate through a 100x100 array and pick every time four neighbours (one left of the center node, one above, one right and one below), like in the picture below

[image: matrix with red as center node and blue as neighbours]

the red one is the center node and the blue ones are the neighbours. I struggle to find a convenient way in MATLAB to pick randomly one of the neighbours.

Comment: How did you deal with the boundary (corner and edge) ?

Comment: @obchardon I replicate the matrices in all directions. So if I would be on position (1,1) the left neighbour would be (1,100) and the top neighbour would be (100,1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes that

- Each entry is replaced by one of its original neighbours, *independently* of what happens to other entries.
- Each neighbour has the *same probability* of being picked.
- Neighbourhood is defined *cyclically*. Thus, for example, in the first column the "left" neighbour belongs to the last column.

The code builds a cyclically extended matrix for convenience, and then uses linear indexing to (randomly) select the neighbours.

```
x = [10 20 30 40; 50 60 70 80; 90 100 110 120]; % example data
x_ext = x([end 1:end 1], [end 1:end 1]); % cyclically extended matrix
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (2:size(x,1)+1).', (1:size(x,2))*(size(x,1)+2)); % linear indices
    % of the original matrix in the extended matrix
delta = [-1 1 -size(x_ext,1) size(x_ext,1)]; % possible displacements for neighbours,
    % as linear indices
r = delta(randi(4, size(x))); % generate random displacements
result = x_ext(ind + r); % pick neighbours in extended matrix
```

Example:

```
>> x
x =
    10    20    30    40
    50    60    70    80
    90   100   110   120
>> result
result =
    20    30    70    30
    90   100    60   120
    50   110    70    40
```